# Return two design elements in builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, scaffold

```
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
...
...
...

builder: (BuildContext context) { //BuildContext context
              final innerScrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
              return TabMedium(
                sc: innerScrollController,
                tc: _tabController,
              );
              return  BannerAdAdmob();            
            }
```

For now, it shows only TabMedium() view. How can I put top & bottom these views?

What do I get?

[image]

What do I want?

[image]

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `Column` ??

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
return Scaffold(
...
...
...
builder: (BuildContext context) { //BuildContext context
          final innerScrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
          return Column(
         
           children:[
             Expanded(
               child:TabMedium(
                       sc: innerScrollController,
                       tc: _tabController,
               ),
             ),
             BannerAdAdmob(),
           ],
          );         
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add two `return`, only first return will be executed.
If you want to show two widget as you show in the picture you can use `Column`.

```
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
...
...
...

builder: (BuildContext context) { //BuildContext context
              final innerScrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
              return Column(
               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
               children:[
                 Expanded(
                   child:TabMedium(
                           sc: innerScrollController,
                           tc: _tabController,
                   ),
                 ),
                 BannerAdAdmob(),
               ],
              );         
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens bcs you just return one of them.

try to put them in a Column, maybe like this:

(I did not Compiled it but it should work)

```
builder: (BuildContext context) { //BuildContext context
          final innerScrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
          return Column(
           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children[
              TabMedium(
              sc: innerScrollController,
              tc: _tabController,
              ),
              BannerAdAdmob(),  
            ],


          );
          
              
        }
```